# Joining X and Y axis

Tags: r, boxplot

been trying to follow but not being able to solve [Removing top and right borders from boxplot frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470114/removing-top-and-right-borders-from-boxplot-frame-in-r)

```
boxplot(exp2A$weight~exp2A$'pellet formulation', 
xlab= 'pellet formulation', ylab= 'weight', 
par(family = "Times New Roman"), frame.plot = FALSE, axis(side=1))
```

[image: Box plot with that code above achived]

I would want the X and Y lines to meet at 0

Comment: you have categorical variables.. what's the point of meeting at 0?

Comment: none other than I've been asked to do it that way

Answer (score 1):

You use `par(xaxs="i"..)` to use the exact limits, see [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prepplot/vignettes/prepplotOverview.pdf) and what remains is to set the y limits manually and add the x axis labels. I really think it doesn't make much sense to pass through zero when your x axis is categorical:

```
par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
b = boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ Species,frame.plot=FALSE,data=iris,
xaxt="n",ylim=c(0,5))
axis(side=1,at=0:length(b$names),labels=c("",b$names))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a go now.